# Proof that $\left(\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{(-1)^n}{z-n\pi}\right)^2=\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=-N}^N \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{z-n\pi}\right)^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

How would I prove the following identity? $$\left(\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=-N}^N\frac{(-1)^n}{z-n\pi}\right)^2=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^N \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{z-n\pi}\right)^2$$

Can this be proved algebraically?

Comment: The first sum is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: But it still converges...

Comment: It looks wrong but it's correct. Both series (should) converge to $\operatorname{csc}^2 z$, but I don't know how to prove that the series on the right converges to the same function.

Comment: The neatest proof would be given by Carlson’s theorem, by considering the fact that the reciprocal of left and right hand sides have the same set of zeroes. Algebraically, residue theorem/Poisson’s summation formula can be used to find the closed form of the sums. Nothing difficult, but the algebra could be a little tedious.

Comment: In addition, due to conditional convergence on the left hand side, the sum should be interpreted as $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum^N_{n=-N}$$, and hence can be rewritten as $$\frac1z+2z\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{z^2-(n\pi)^2}$$

Comment: @Szeto Corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f(z)=\left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^n}{z-n\pi}\right)^2-\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{z-n\pi}\right)^2$$ It is $2\pi$-periodic, entire (because $\left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^n}{z-n\pi}\right)^2$ is even), grouping the terms of the first series by two shows it is $O(|z|)$ on $\Re(z)\in [-\pi,\pi]$ thus it is $O(z)$ on the whole complex plane and $g(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}$ is entire and bounded thus constant. Since $zg(z)$ is periodic then $g(z)=0$ and $f(z)=f(0)$.

To find $f(0)$ : the second series is absolutely convergent thus it vanishes at $i\infty$, not sure how to deal with the first series, anyway since we know it is bounded away from its poles, it is immediate that it is $= \frac{1}{\sin( z)}+C$ and $C=0$ because it is odd.